# JwtSecurityToken moved to a new namespace. How to I leverage it in new projects?

Tags: azure, asp.net-identity, .net-assembly, azure-mobile-services, claims-based-identity

[This Azure Mobile Apps library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Login/0.3.36) returns a JWT that is located in the following file:

```
Assembly System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=4.0.20622.1351, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

When I inspect the JwtSecurityToken, I get this:

```
public class JwtSecurityToken : System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken
   Member of System.IdentityModel.Tokens
   Version: 4.0.20622.1351
```

However I can only locate this comparable replacement in a newer DLL (version 5.1.0.0 of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt)

```
public class JwtSecurityToken :  Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken
   Member of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
```

**Question**

How am I supposed to use the linked library that seems to require the old assembly, but the only option available to me is in the new assembly and with a new name?

Comment: As my test, `Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Login -Version 0.3.36` install System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt (version 4.0.2.205111437) . For your issue, I would suggest you submit a [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216254-mobile-apps).

Answer (score 0):

The System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt v5.x libraries are for .NET Core.  Azure Mobile Apps uses .NET Framework 4.x, so it requires the older libraries.

Install Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server - it will require the right version as a dependency.